# Integrate Google Meet video calls in iOS webview

Tags: ios, swift, webview, google-meet

In my iOS app I am trying to open Google Meet meetings in the web view. But When I tried to open meeting url it redirect me to install app page.

[image]

So I tried to open force desktop view of it and I changed customUserAgent of WKWebView as follows

```
webview.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
```

By using this user agent I am able to open desktop view but it is giving error of unsupported browser.

any help would be appreciated

[image]